# What is $UU^*$ if $U$ is a linear isometry?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $U: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a linear isometry and $d>n$,does the matrix $UU^*$ have any particular structure then? For example if $d=n$ then the result will be the identity matrix, but this cannot be the answer now, due to rank violations. What can I hope for? I am pretty sure that it is a matrix of rank $n$. Can we say more?

I suspect that it is the projection onto $ran(U^*)$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can just check whether $UU^*$ is a projection or not.
We have $(UU^*)^* = (U^*)^*U^* =U U^*$ and $(UU^*)^2 = UU^*UU^*=U1U^*=UU^*$.
So $UU^*$ is a projection.

Furthermore, for $x \in U(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have $x=Uy$ and thus $UU^*x=UU^*Uy=Uy =x$, thus $U(\mathbb{R}^n)$ stays invariant under $UU^*$.
For $x \perp U(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $0 = \langle Uy , x \rangle = \langle y , U^*x \rangle$, which is only possible if $U^*x = 0$, and thus $UU^*x=0$.

So $UU^*$ is the projection onto $U(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I would even say [*orthogonal* projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) as it is self-adjoint.